# Problems viewing sitefinity site in localhost

Tags: asp.net, localhost, sitefinity

I'm currently working on a site that uses sitefinity 3.7. After copying the files to my hard-drive using source safe, I tried viewing the page in my localhost when the following error appeared:

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Cms.Engine, Version=3.1.3311.24714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85fd314cb21bc432' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Cms.Engine, Version=3.1.3311.24714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85fd314cb21bc432' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Telerik.Cms.Engine, Version=3.1.3311.24714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85fd314cb21bc432' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Cms.Engine, Version=3.1.3311.24714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85fd314cb21bc432' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
   Telerik.Utilities.TypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +579
   Telerik.Utilities.StringTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +108
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.XmlConfigProvider.LoadAttributes(ConfigElement element, XmlReader reader) +321
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.XmlConfigProvider.LoadElement(ConfigElement element, XmlReader reader, Stack`1 stack) +761
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.XmlConfigProvider.LoadSection(ConfigSection section) +389
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.ConfigProvider.GetSection() +279
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.ConfigManager.GetSection() +104
   Telerik.Framework.Web.ControlUtils..cctor() +64

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Telerik.Framework.Web.ControlUtils' threw an exception.]
   Telerik.Framework.Web.ControlUtils.GetTemplate(String virtualPath) +0
   Telerik.Search.WebControls.SearchBox.get_LayoutTemplate() +50
   Telerik.Search.WebControls.SearchBox.CreateChildControls() +90
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

---

Things I've tried:

- Changing the permissions of the folder (both DefaultAppPool and Network Services)
- Getting the latest version of the site again.
- Checked the web.config and reconfigured connection strings to point to database (probably unrelated)
- Recompiled the site - no fix

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with not being able to find the correct version of the Sitefinity assemblies, or not finding assemblies at all. Do you have the BIN folder of the application in source control? I can help better if you show the full list of files in the project. Are you sure you didn't compile it against another version of Sitefinity?

Comment: We figured out that the web.config file was corrupt. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question though -